Index data containing large integers into Elasticsearch
What would I like to achieve?
I need to index some events into Elasticsearch. These events are formatted as JSON and can contain large numbers (the specific data I'm working with goes up to 2^128 but the question is relevant for every type of integer that does not fit into 64 bits, which is the width of elastic's long/ unsigned_long types):
{
    [...]
    "some_large_number": 123456789012345678901234567890,
    [...]
}

What does not work?
Any integer type Elastic supports
Simply using dynamic mapping or explicitly setting the type to any of the integer types available in elastic will fail to index the data with an error like this:

Numeric value (1.2345679e+29) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)

Coercing the data to string
I do not need to do arithmetic on these fields in elastic, so the semantics of a numeric field are not needed.
This means that simply storing the data as a text ("123456789012345678901234567890") would be an option.
{
  "properties": {
    "some_large_number": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}

However, while setting the mapping of the field in question to text does allow the data to be indexed, the value is not as expected:
Instead, it will be converted to scientific notation ("1.2345679e+29"), leading to a loss of information.
Changing the data on the producer-side
I cannot change the incoming data, since I have no control over the producer.
Adding another tool that does preprocessing
While not strictly impossible, I would like to avoid this solution:
Inserting some other tool into the telemetry chain that does some pre-processing on the data (e.g. add quotation marks to the JSON) would certainly solve the issue, but it seems like overkill for this seemingly tiny problem which I would hope should have a simple solution in Elastic itself.
